# c++ global locale - unknown symbols when printing a number

Tags: c++, locale

I added locale as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/76013/how-do-i-add-locale-to-ubuntu-server)

```
sudo locale-gen ru_RU
sudo locale-gen ru_RU.UTF-8
sudo update-locale
```

Now I want to test output like this:

```
std::cout << std::locale("").name().c_str() << '\n';
std::cout << 1000.01 << '\n';
std::locale::global(std::locale("ru_RU.utf8") );
std::cout.imbue(std::locale());
std::cout << std::locale().name().c_str() << '\n';
std::cout << std::fixed << 12345678.01 << '\n';
```

and get this:

```
en_US.UTF-8
1000.01
ru_RU.utf8
12�345�678,010000
```

Why do I get this unknown symbols?

UPD:

In hex it's A0 (but only for my system):

```
31 32 A0 33 34 35 A0 36 37 38 2C 30 31 30 30 30 30 0A  0
```

Comment: Redirect to a file & get the actual UTF-8 byte sequence via a hex editor/viewer?

Comment: It's `A0` in hex. Why can a normal space appear like a question symbol?

Comment: Weird, it's `0xC2` on my Debian box.